# Android VideoView Freezes after running for long time (more than 24hrs)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-videoview

I'm making an app that plays videos in a loop. It is supposed to play forever as long as the device is on. I have a list of videos in a variable and I use index to loop through every video to play it. The app works fine but when it runs for many hours (more than 20hrs) at a certain point the videoView freezes on a single frame and it won't call `onCompletion` or `onError` listeners. I run this on devices with API 17 and API 19. They both get the same error.
Here is my code (two methods that do the play loop):

```
public void playNextVideo(){
    if(playIndex < 0) { playIndex = 0; }
     if(allPromos.size() > 0) {
          try {
              Promo p = allPromos.get(playIndex);
              playVideo(p);
          } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
              Log.w("EXCEPTION", e);
              isPlaying = false;
          } finally {
              playIndex++;
              if (playIndex >= allPromos.size()) {
                  playIndex = 0;
              }
          }
      } else {
          Log.d("PlayNextVideo", "No videos in the playlist");
      }
}

public void playVideo(Promo promo) {
    File videoFile = new File(promo.getLocal_link());
    if (!videoFile.exists()) {
        Log.d("VIDEOPLAYER", "Video " + playIndex + " Has been skipped. File not found");
        playNextVideo();
    } else {
        if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
            videoView.stopPlayback();
        }
        videoView.setVideoPath(promo.getLocal_link());
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(false);
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.stopPlayback();
                playNextVideo();
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.d("MEDIA PLAYER ERROR", what + ", " + extra);
                videoView.stopPlayback();
                try{
                    mp.release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.w("RELEASE EXCEPTION", e);
                }
                playNextVideo();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the question? Seems you have found a bug.

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a logcat because I am running the app on devices that I cant figure out usb debug interface/connection (china version of digital signage android devices).

Comment: @ringunger I found the same issue that when video plays for a long duration like even for 14 hours, the app freezes. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @DevAndroid 
No! I ended up implementing a schedule reboot for the devices to avoid the issue